# Detect hover multiple times without an 'out' event

Tags: jquery, html, canvas

I'm building an app that uses the HTML 5 canvas, and it outputs a grid as just lines on the canvas. I want to be able to have the user hover over a cell in the grid and get the cell coordinates via a tooltip. Right now I'm outputting to the console.

I can capture a hover event in jQuery, but it only gives me the coordinates of the cell I entered on, and the cell I left. Is is possible via jQuery or a plugin to detect when the mouse pauses over an area to fire an event? I tried hoverIntent, but that just delays the event but doesn't allow me to fire off events on the same element without exiting and re-entering the element.

Answer (score 0):

If I was doing this I'd try something like jquery mousemove event for coordinates, and use a defferred object with a timeout for your specified time to define a pause. I'm no jquery genius it just seems like an asynchronous event you want and thats what google came up with for me. The best examples I've found are on the jquery docs @  http://api.jquery.com/deferred.promise/.